# Load standalone js library using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add this library to my project: https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesJS/tree/master/Phaser/Demos

I use webpack for merging all libraries, it produces such output in `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

I'd like to inject required files between `vendor.bundle.js` - which, as I suspect contains all remaining libraries merged into one file - and `bundle.js` - which contains my game. I could also inject them at the end of `vector.bundle.js`, it doesn't matter for me. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Let's say that's the list of files I need to load:

```
<script src="./libs/dragonBones/dragonBones.js"></script>

<script src="./out/DragHelper.js"></script>
<script src="./out/BaseDemo.js"></script>
<script src="./out/HelloDragonBones.js"></script>
<script src="./out/AnimationBase.js"></script>
<script src="./out/DragonBonesEvent.js"></script>
<script src="./out/AnimationLayer.js"></script>
<script src="./out/BoneOffset.js"></script>
<script src="./out/InverseKinematics.js"></script>
<script src="./out/BoundingBox.js"></script>
<script src="./out/ReplaceSlotDisplay.js"></script>
<script src="./out/ReplaceAnimation.js"></script>
<script src="./out/CoreElement.js"></script>
<script src="./out/PerformanceTest.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to modify `index.html` template to include them between these two files mentioned earlier? Or maybe there is better way of doing that?

Comment: no, you need to include them somewhere in your entry point.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work